# Cron job does not seem to finish

Tags: cron

I have a cron job running every 10 minutes. If I call the function anywhere else, the script finishes running within ~5 minutes errorless and does what it is supposed to do.

When looking into the timeline view of `AOE Scheduler` however, I see all cron jobs of this kind not finishing.

There's no error in any log file and as I said, the script itself does not throw errors. What could this all be about?

Comment: What do you mean by "If I call the function anywhere else" Is this not a standard Magento cron?

Comment: @brentwpeterson it is. But for example, I tried executing the function when loading a page of my module in the backend for example (then I would see errors because php is set to strict)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is most likely what happened. Correct me if I didn't get something right.

I observed, that if the task took longer than 10 minutes, it would not output any logging anymore. So that means it is stopped forcefully and marked with no finish time.

I just made sure no task will ever run longer than the time window until it is called again and that seemed to have done the job for now.